# RecyclerView doesn't display all items with ScrollView and middle items are streched using NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have a grid supported by recyclerview inside a ConstraintLayout inside a ScrollView.

Although 20 items are inserted in `setList()` (I debugged it), only 9 items are displayed when using `ScrollView`

When I switch to `NestedScrollView` all 20 items are displayed, but the items in the middle are streched. Not the images, but it seems that there is a background behind streched 3 times the actual size of the item/image.

I'm using androidx libraries.

### Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:context=".ui.details.DetailsFragment">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/detail_backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/clapperboard"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play_symbol"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/detail_backdrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/detail_backdrop"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/detail_backdrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline_white_96dp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/details_progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        Some other views...

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_my_list_details"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/my_list_at_details"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/wish_list_btn"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/wish_list_btn"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/wish_list_btn" />


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_recommended"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_my_list_details"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

### List item layout

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/movie_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/movie_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_poster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:src="@drawable/clapperboard" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

### Adapter

```
package com.lacourt.myapplication.ui.details

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Point
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
import android.util.DisplayMetrics
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Display
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.lacourt.myapplication.AppConstants
import com.lacourt.myapplication.R
import com.lacourt.myapplication.dto.DbMovieDTO
import com.lacourt.myapplication.ui.OnItemClick
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.movie_list_item.view.*

class RecommendedAdapter(
    private val context: Context?,
    private val onItemClick: OnItemClick,
    private var list: ArrayList<DbMovieDTO>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecommendedHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecommendedHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_recommended, parent, false)
        return RecommendedHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecommendedHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.d("grid-log", "onBindViewHolder() called, position = $position, list.size = ${list.size}")
        // get device dimensions
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        (context as Activity).windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

        val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels

        val maxHeight= width.div(3) * 1.5
        holder.poster.minimumHeight = maxHeight.toInt()

        holder.apply {
           Picasso.get()
                .load("${AppConstants.TMDB_IMAGE_BASE_URL_W185}${list[position].poster_path}")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.clapperboard)
                .into(poster)

            cardView.setOnClickListener {
                val id = list[position].id
                if (id != null)
                    onItemClick.onItemClick(id)
                else
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Sorry. Can not load this movie. :/",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()

            }
        }

    }

    fun setList(list: List<DbMovieDTO>) {
        Log.d("grid-log", "setList() called")
        this.list.clear()
        this.list.addAll(list)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

class RecommendedHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var poster = itemView.iv_poster
    var cardView = itemView.movie_card_view
}
```

Any solutions for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Since it may help someone in the future, I found a solution:

I just added `holder.cardView.layoutParams.height = maxHeight.toInt()` to `onBindViewHolder` of my adapter class and now every item layout is in the correct size.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a constraint layout, you should let the constraints set the size, in general.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_recommended"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="dp"
        ...
```

`0dp` in this case means let the constraints set the value.

Comment: Yes, but i'm using a scrollView, so the layout is not limited to the parent. I have no ```layoutBottom_toBottom``` constraint. Otherwise, it would not be possible to scroll the screen.